# Advanced webview not loading URL properly

Tags: android, webview

I am using advanced webview in my app. I followed the steps as listed in https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView.

The problem is , the webview is not loading the URL properly, meaning that, the screen is not aligned properly and in few websites, I am not able to click the buttons.

I use `myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` in my code.

Will `setJavaScriptEnabled` work in advanced webview?

Comment: In your app Manifest file add this line (android:usesCleartextTraffic="true") under application tag

Comment: @xaif it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and WebStorage are enabled by default according to Github repository:
https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Did you try this?

```
mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.setListener(this, this);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.org/");
```

If that is not working try this use case as for normal WebView

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I need to use advanced webview as it has more options than the normal one. I have written my script exactly as in the link.

Comment: Then you don't need web.settingsJavaScriptEnabled(true); part

Comment: Check behaviour with another web link,maybe it s your link that is cuasing those problems

Comment: This is not android problem,this is web problem that was caused by website you are referring to.Site is not mobile friendly so WebView is having trouble processing it.

Comment: But in the normal webview, it was working fine. How can I solve this problem?